# Basic stored produre returns error

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I try to code my first stored procedure in MySQL Workbench and somehow it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `check_completeness`()
BEGIN
    -- drop table
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `check_language`;

    -- create table
    CREATE TABLE `check_language`(
        `id` int,
        `lang` varchar(8),
        `count` int,
        `complete` boolean
    );

    INSERT INTO `check_language` 
            (`id`, `lang`, `count`, `complete`) 
        VALUES 
            (
                NULL, 
                (SELECT tbl_language_code from `vw_qa_envi` GROUP BY tbl_language_code), 
                (SELECT COUNT(tbl_language_code)  from `vw_qa_envi` GROUP BY tbl_language_code),
                (SELECT IF(COUNT(tbl_language_code) = 148, 1, 0) FROM `vw_qa_envi` GROUP BY tbl_language_code)
            );

END
```

When I execute each singe SQL query alone, it works perfect. But when I try to execute the whole stored procedure, it doesn't work.

I get an `error code 1242`.

> Subquery returns more than 1 row.

Comment: The error message is one of the more specific/helpful ones you can get... All of your sub-queries can/will return multiple results.  I have no idea how to help you, because I don't know what you're attempting to do here.

Comment: Check these queries ` (SELECT tbl_language_code from `vw_qa_envi` GROUP BY tbl_language_code), 
                (SELECT COUNT(tbl_language_code)  from `vw_qa_envi` GROUP BY tbl_language_code),
                (SELECT IF(COUNT(tbl_language_code) = 148, 1, 0) FROM `vw_qa_envi` GROUP BY tbl_language_code)` separately and ensure each returns single value

Comment: The error message says it all.  How else can we explain it to you?  Run each sub-query.  One or more of then return more than 1 row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to `insert` one single row with the `values ()` clause, but your queries return more than 1 row. Instead of the `values ()` clause you should specify the query directly. And don't split it into multiple queries, use one!

Try this one:

```
INSERT INTO `check_language` (`lang`, `count`, `complete`) 
SELECT tbl_language_code, COUNT(tbl_language_code), IF(COUNT(tbl_language_code) = 148, 1, 0)
FROM `vw_qa_envi` 
GROUP BY tbl_language_code
```

When you just insert `NULL` into a column, just leave the column out. That's why I removed the `id` column.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to set a LIMIT 1 in your subquery
example:
`SELECT tbl_language_code from`vw_qa_envi`GROUP BY tbl_language_code LIMIT 1`

but the problem remain because you don't say if the element is right, because it return many element..